# Non-proprietary (Python friendly) alternatives to Cplex and Gurobi

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, cplex, gurobi

I have implemented a pure binary integer combinatorial optimization routine within a Python module (importing `gurobipy`), and experimented with relaxing a few constraints so some variables may assume values 0, 1 or 2, until I ran first into time-to-result latency problems then into memory problems. That initial effort was based on Gurobi, which I discovered on that occasion... and liked, because it has provisions to build [thread-safe compute environments](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_env2.html#pythonmethod:Env) when multi-threading, and it offers a model namespace in which the analyst may write out constraints and the objective function and embed them in code.

I now need to replace the Gurobi solver because my earlier installation is reaching its free one-year term limit. I would like to be able to call a FOSS ILP/MIP solver into my python module. Although I saw a couple of references to `lpsolve()` (e.g. [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/9334)), my issue is that I really don't know what is and what isn't available out there for Python v3.9+ environments.

I am looking for a stable solver (no beta implementation) with a Python API.

Comment: [pySCIPopt](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt), [Python-Mip](https://www.python-mip.com), [Pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) and [Pyomo](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo) are probably the most commonly used python modelling frameworks. Given that you're switching from Gurobi, the first one might be worth a try since it's very similar to gurobipy and supports a couple of special constraint types as well.

Comment: Thank you, @joni. I will start with pySCIPopt and continue with Pyomo.  great help.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: got it: no fluff here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HiGHS](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS), [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/) and [CBC](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc) solvers with using PYOMO or other Pyomo supported solvers. Also you can use [google or-tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools) CP solver if you write CP model, google CP solver is [very powerfull](https://www.minizinc.org/challenge.html). PYOMO and GurobiPY have similar modelling structure. For example:

- Model defining:
  Gurobi: `model = gurobipy.Model("LP Example")` Pyomo: `model = pyomo.ConcreteModel()`
- Variable adding: Gurobi: `x = model.addVar(name="x")` Pyomo: `model.x = pyomo.Var(within=NonNegativeReals)`

If you compare gurobipy and pyomo models side-by-side, you can see similarities and convert easily.

Before deciding solver, you can find performance benchmark of free and commercial solvers on [here.](https://mattmilten.github.io/mittelmann-plots/)

Comment: As commented before to @joni, I will start with pySCIPopt and continue with Pyomo. Thank you.